# Watching contracts on ethereum and polygon for Transfer events

Tags: ethers.js

What would be involved in watching a few specific contract addresses for Transfer event on Ethereum or Polygon?

[Moralis Streams API](https://moralis.io/blog/streams/) is what I'm using now but it can get pricey with the number of daily computes and records.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

At the lowest code implementation level, you can use Ethereum's [subscription API](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/pubsub), in your particular case, you can subscribe to the logs.

Below is a sample code you can try out. This code subscribes to USDT's transfer event. It is modified from [this](https://support.chainstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403518123161-Subscribing-to-smart-contract-events-with-web3-js) tutorial.

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
//visit Chainstack doc for more information:
//https://support.chainstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403518123161-Subscribing-to-smart-contract-events-with-web3-js?utm_term=&utm_campaign=co_search&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=7102112062&hsa_cam=17317323485&hsa_grp=142306614157&hsa_ad=627441674301&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=dsa-19959388920&hsa_kw=&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=CjwKCAiAzp6eBhByEiwA_gGq5GUtO3UTrbzInqsITVNlC7Ov-GKZR1MH47BBkw5zqUA6he2BacqE0RoCn6MQAvD_BwE

// ws url
const ws_url = "wss://ws-nd-610-406-547.fill-in-your-ws-endpoint-here.com/fill-in-your-ws-endpoint-here"
const web3 = new Web3(ws_url)

// subscribe to logs
// for SushiSwap: MasterChef LP Staking Pool withdraw events on mainnet
var logs = web3.eth
    .subscribe(
        "logs", {
            //SushiSwap: MasterChef LP Staking Pool
            address: "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
            topics: [
                //Transfer (index_topic_1 address from, index_topic_2 address to, uint256 value)
                "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"
            ]
        },
        function(error, result) {
            if (!error) console.log(result);
        }
    )
    .on("connected", function(subscriptionId) {
        console.log("sub id:" + subscriptionId);
    })
    .on("data", function(log) {
        console.log(log);
    })
    .on("changed", function(log) {});

//keep this code alive
setInterval(() => {}, 1 << 30);
```

The WebSocket endpoint in this sample is just a dummy address, you will need to change that. If you need one, feel free to try [our service](https://chainstack.com), the developer plan is free and it comes with 3 million free requests.

Hope this helps.